# Activiti complex objects

Tags: activiti

I noticed that when I create a complex variable using the APIs, the object is saved as a byte array which makes it impossible to search tasks based on values in this object,
Is there any way to save the object as a json object or any other simpler form ?

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer to your question would be to create a custom serializer/deserializer for your complex type as documented here:

http://blog.progs.be/628/activiti-variables-json

However, I recommend you consider making use of the Activiti Event system to export process events to a nosql store such as Elasticsearch. This way, you can easily search and filter on process variables for reporting purposes.

A sample project demonstrating a simple Elasticsearch implementation for Camunda (

https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-elasticsearch

Comment: Does that apply on activiti that is shipped with alfresco ?

Comment: The engine is identical, but the API that is exposed has been "dumbed down". I haven't actually extended the event system with the Alfresco One embedded activiti engine, but I doubt it would be very hard.

Comment: so the solutions provided above wont work, am I right ?